# How do I add if isBlank keeps failing

Tags: powerbi

Current I have this and works well

CALCULATE(if(ISBLANK(PDR[Count test]),0,COUNTROWS(Pdr)))

How do I add a '0' or 'NA' if the field has no data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
COALESCE( COUNTROWS(Pdr), 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that